# Get index of row in table using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to get index of each row in this table using angularJS

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat = "cust in costomers">
     <td> cust.name </td>
     <td> cust.phone </td>
     <td> cust.address </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to have a variable that contains the index of each row not to just display it

Comment: what does `variable that contains the index` mean? Explain intended usage

Comment: Data in each row will be changed according to the need of changing it So instead of sending it to server then receiving it again to display it for the user I want to change it directly without the need of getting it from server each time I change an index of the row

Comment: don't even need index for that, pass `cust` as argument to any controller methods. Still not very clear what higher level issue is

Answer (score 12):

you can use $index

```
   <tr ng-repeat = "cust in costomers">
     <td> {{$index}} </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you should be using the `<tr>` tag to place your `ng-repeat` directive.
You can use `ng-repeat's` **`$index`** property.  See `ng-repeat`'s **[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)**.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat = "cust in costomers">
      <td> {{$index}} </td>
      <td> {{cust.name}} </td>
      <td> {{cust.phone}} </td>
      <td> {{cust.address}} </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to have a variable that contains the index of each row not to just display it

Comment: can you tell me your use case in having each item have an index property? perhaps there is another way to solve your problem?

Comment: Data in each row will be changed according to the need of changing it
So instead of sending it to server then receiving it again to display it for the user
I want to change it directly without the need of getting it from server each time I change an index of the row

Answer (score 2):

$index works fine when the ng-repeat is not filtered. If you use a filter, it might be better to use indexOf(). Example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="filterCustomers" placeholder="search...">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat = "cust in costomers | filter:filterCustomers">
      <td> {{costomers.indexOf(cust) + 1}} </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your own variable as `index` you can use this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat = "(index, cust) in costomers">
     <td> {{index}} </td>
     <td> cust.name </td>
     <td> cust.phone </td>
     <td> cust.address </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```